# Separating out implementations without exposing helpers or causing code repetition

Tags: c++, refactoring

I have a `.cxx` file with a number of functions in it which are exposed for general usage (`toolkit.cxx`, with corresponding `toolkit.h`).

The implementation of several of these functions requires a class which won't be used anywhere else (`Fetcher`).

At present I have a `Fetcher.h`, but all the implementations of its methods are in `toolkit.cxx`.

Things are now changing, and two types of `Fetcher` are needed - child classes `SimpleFetcher` and `FancyFetcher`.

This is too much code to keep all in `toolkit.cxx`, so I'm separating it out with 3 extra implementation files (`fetcher.cxx` for the functions implemented by the parent, and `simple_fetcher.cxx` and `fancy_fetcher.cxx` for the child ones).

My trouble is, I have a number of helper functions which are used throughout these implementations, as well as in the `toolkit.cxx` functions, which I don't want to duplicate or expose beyond these source files.

At present they are implemented in an unnamed namespace in `toolkit.cxx`, but that won't be visible to the new `.cxx` implementation files.

What are the options in a case like this?

Comment: *"This is too much code to keep all in toolkit.cxx"* [citation-required], so to speak. My rule for how much code to keep in a file is akin to the single-responsibility principle. If all of that code is *only* used by the `toolkit.h` header, then it's all implementation details and shouldn't be separated out.

Comment: Keeping it together is always an option, I just feel it's a bit clumsy when I'm modifying it and would be easier to keep track of things with a bit of separation. Not experienced in c++ though, so that may be a bad plan...

Comment: In my project, I have several `foo_helpers.h` files for helper functions used in the "foo" feature. These headers are included in all `cpp` files implementing the "foo" feature.